# Getting names/values of multiple properties

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Lets say I have one method, which extracts property name and value:

```
public TModel Get (Expression<Func<object>> param)
{
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var propertyName= ((MemberExpression)param.Body).Member.Name;

            var value = param.Compile()();

            // GetTableName() returns table name of TModel
            var query = $"SELECT * FROM {GetTableName()} WHERE {propertyName}='{value}'";

            var output = connection.Query<TModel>(query);
            connection.Dispose();
            return output.FirstOrDefault();

        }
}
```

and using it as:

```
var model = Get(() => foo.FirstProperty);
```

However, if I want to get name and value from the unknown number of properties, I do this:

```
public TModel Get(params Expression<Func<object>>[] param)
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var query = new StringBuilder();

            query.Append($"SELECT * FROM {GetTableName()} WHERE ");
            for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
            {
                var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)param[i].Body).Member.Name;

                var value = param[i].Compile()();

                query.Append($"{propertyName} = '{value}'");
                if (i + 1 < param.Length) query.Append(" AND ");
            }

            var output = connection.Query<TModel>(query.ToString());
            connection.Dispose();
            return output.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

But, implementation looks a bit 'ugly' and verbose:

```
var model = Get(() => foo.FirstProperty, () => foo.SecondProperty); // and so on
```

I could send manualy name of the property + value, however, I would like to keep the implementation as simple as possible and less verbose.

Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: If this is code you've written, and it works, and you'd like a review of all aspects of your code, this *might* be better off on [codereview.se], but I'd check their help center first before asking.

Comment: Are you doing it this way for speed reasons?  Reflection already has this functionality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do this because I'm using Oracle database and Dapper. However, Dapper.contrib is not very friendly with oracle and I do not want to write every single query manually. Therefore I came up with an idea to have one method which will build that query based on given properties. My code snippet works, however, as I mentioned, It looks a bit 'verbose', especially for 3+ parameters which will force to write ' () => ' every time I pass a property

Comment: I think we'd have to see more of your code to come up with a solution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've edited my post.

Comment: Is this a different API than Dapper.Contrib?  Because Dapper.Contrib is just `connection.Get<TModel>(id)`.  Can the consumer still use the original API?

Comment: It is Dapper.Contrib. If I use connection.Get<T>(dynamic id), I'm getting ''ORA-00936: missing expression'. Similar with others Contrib methods. I believe, that underlying sql query is slightly different in oracle. I.e. if I want to get/insert DateTime from/in database, it throws bunch of exceptions. And this is a reason why I manually build a query and passing it.

Answer (score 0):

we can shorten the expressions by making Get generic, giving Get the foo instance, and changing the expressions to T, object so that they can accept foo.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SO60378405
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new SomeContainer("hello", 123);
            Get(foo, s => s.SomeString, s => s.SomeInt);
        }
        static void Get<T>(T foo, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressions)
        {
            foreach (var expression in expressions)
            {
                var memberExpression = GetMemberExpression(expression);
                var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
                var propertyGetter = expression.Compile();
                var propertyValue = propertyGetter(foo);
                Console.WriteLine($"{propertyName} = '{propertyValue}'");
            }
        }
        static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            switch (expression.Body)
            {
                case MemberExpression memberExpression:
                    return memberExpression; //string
                case UnaryExpression unaryExpression when unaryExpression.Operand is MemberExpression operandMemberExpression:
                    return operandMemberExpression; //int, decimal
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
    public class SomeContainer
    {
        public string SomeString { get; set; }
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public SomeContainer(string someString, int someInt)
        {
            SomeString = someString;
            SomeInt = someInt;
        }
    }
}
```